# Express vector as linear combination of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

let's say I have two vectors:

$u = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

I can easily express   $\; w = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ as a linear combination of u and v.

My problem is: how can I express a vector **v** as a linear combination of **n** vectors?

I searched all around and I just found about expressing a $R^n$ vector as linear combination of exactly $n$ vectors from $R^n$.

- $[u_1 \; u_2 \; u_3 \; | \; v]$
- apply gaussian elimination;

But I didn't discover how to express it with **k** vectors ($ k \ne n$), for example, if I apply this method with u and v to find w, this is what happens:

$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&2&3\\
      1&1&2\\
      1&1&2
    \end{array}
\right] $   applying elimination: $ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&2&3\\
      0&-1&-1\\
      0&0&0
    \end{array}
\right] $

And I know the answer for $\;au + bv = w\;$ is $\;(a = 1, \;b = 1)$ but I couldn't extract this information from the matrix.

Formalizing: Given a $R^n$ vector, how can I express it as a linear combination of $k$ vectors, where $k \ne n$ ?

Comment: Why couldn't you get $a=1=b$ from the matrix? The two rows tell you that $a+2b=3$ and $-b=-1$, which implies that $a=b=1$.

Comment: a side note, if k is less than n, you may not be able to express your vector using k vectors

Comment: Continue row-reduction until you’ve produced the rref of the matrix. You’ll be able to read the answer directly from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wish to determine how to solve $\lambda_1 u+\lambda_2 v=w$ where
\begin{align*}
u &= \langle 1,1,1\rangle &
v &= \langle 2,1,1\rangle &
w &= \langle a,b,c\rangle
\end{align*}
To do so, form the augmented system
$$
M = 
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & 2 & a \\
1 & 1 & b \\
1 & 1 & c
\end{array}\right]
$$
The system $M$ can be row-reduced with the following steps

- add $-1$ times row 1 to row 2
- add $-1$ times row 1 to row 3
- scale row 2 by $-1$
- add $-2$ times row 2 to row 1
- add $1$ times row 2 to row 3

These row-reductions gives
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & 0 & -a + 2 \, b \\
0 & 1 & a - b \\
0 & 0 & -b + c
\end{array}\right]
$$
This shows that $\lambda_1 u+\lambda_2 v=w$ has a solution if and only if $b=c$. If $b=c$ then $\lambda_1 u+\lambda_2 v=w$ is solved by
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 &=-a+2\,b &
\lambda_2 &= a-b
\end{align*}

In the comments you ask how to express $v=(6,7,6)$ in terms of 
\begin{align*}
u_1 &= (1,1,1) &
u_2 &= (1,1,2) &
u_3 &= (1,2,1) &
u_4 &= (2,1,1)
\end{align*}

This is equivalent to solving the system
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 7 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 6
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row-reducing gives
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
This shows that 
$$
(5-4\,\lambda) u_1 +
\lambda u_2 +
(1+\lambda)u_3 +
\lambda u_4=v
$$
for any $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: but if I have for example 4 vectors 3D to express another one? for example: (1,1,1) (1,1,2) (1,2,1), (2,1,1) to express (6,7,6), what should i do? in the end the answer (right column) was 5 1 0 but 5(1,1,1) + (1,1,2) is not (6,7,6)

Comment: @Daniel I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: can you explain this last equation?